# python async with AsyncKernelManager and Qt not executing

Tags: python, pyside6, qtconsole, qasync

I'm trying to execute code inside a jupyter kernel in a Qt application. I have the below snipplet that is supposed to asynchronously run the code and then print the result

```
import sys
import asyncio

import qasync
from qasync import QApplication
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget
from jupyter_client import AsyncKernelManager


CODE = """print('test')"""


class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        kernel_manager = AsyncKernelManager()
        kernel_manager.start_kernel()

        self.client = kernel_manager.client()
        self.client.start_channels()

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.execute(), loop=loop)

    async def execute(self):
        self.client.execute(CODE)
        response: Coroutine = self.client.get_shell_msg()
        print('Before')
        res = await response
        print('After')


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test()
    test.run()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


main()
```

With the above I get the following output

```
/tmp/test/test.py:16: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'KernelManager._async_start_kernel' was never awaited
  kernel_manager.start_kernel()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/tmp/test/test.py:22: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

so trying to adjust the code according to an example from [qasync](https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync/blob/master/examples/aiohttp_fetch.py)
to something like

```
async def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test()
    test.run()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


qasync.run(main())
```

will result in the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test/test.py", line 40, in <module>
    qasync.run(main())
  File "/tmp/test/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qasync/__init__.py", line 821, in run
    return asyncio.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/tmp/test/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qasync/__init__.py", line 409, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/tmp/test/test.py", line 34, in main
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
RuntimeError: Please destroy the QApplication singleton before creating a new QApplication instance.
```

I'm pretty at lost at this point, does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a QEventLoop, also start_kernel must use await. On the other hand it first imports PySide6 and then the other libraries that depend on PySide6 like qasync so that it can deduce the correct Qt binding.

```py
import sys
import asyncio
from functools import cached_property

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import qasync

from jupyter_client import AsyncKernelManager


CODE = """print('test')"""


class Test:
    @cached_property
    def kernel_manager(self):
        return AsyncKernelManager()

    @cached_property
    def client(self):
        return self.kernel_manager.client()

    async def start(self):
        await self.kernel_manager.start_kernel()
        self.client.start_channels()
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.execute())

    async def execute(self):
        self.client.execute(CODE)
        response = self.client.get_shell_msg()
        print("Before")
        res = await response
        print("After", res)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = qasync.QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    test = Test()
    asyncio.ensure_future(test.start())
    with loop:
        loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```